# How to use enum in Qt?

Tags: c++, enums, qt4

I have a QObject class `Message` and another one named `Request` that inherits the message class. Here's the header file:

```
#ifndef MESSAGE_H
#define MESSAGE_H

#include <QObject>

class Message : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Message(QObject *parent = 0);
    QString Source;
    QString Destination;
    QString Transaction;
    QList<QObject> Content;
signals:

public slots:

};

class Request : public Message
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(RequestTypes)
public:
    explicit Request();
    enum RequestTypes
      {
         SetData,
         GetData
      };

    RequestTypes Type;
    QString Id;
};

#endif // MESSAGE_H
```

Now I want to create a Request in my code and set Type to SetData. How can I do that? Here's my current code which gives the error "'Request::RequestTypes' is not a class or namespace". The header file from above is included in my main programs header file, so `Request` is known and can be created and I can set the other properties - but not the `Type`:

```
Request *r = new Request();
r->Source = "My Source";
r->Destination = "My Destination";
r->Type = Request::RequestTypes::SetData;
```

In other words: I could as well had taken a QString for the `Type` property of a `Request`, but it would be nice and safer to do this with an enum. Can someone please show me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to declare the enum like so:

```
enum class RequestTypes
  {
     SetData,
     GetData
  };
```

in order to use it like you did, but that requires C++11.

The normal usage would be (in your case):
`r->Type = RequestTypes::SetData;`

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use like this;

```
typedef enum 
{
 SetData,
 GetData 
}RequestTypes;
```